# Working with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to know if some key-value pair already exists in shared preferences or not.

```
   sharedPref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedf",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   editor=sharedPref.edit();
   editor.putString("secretKey",e1.getText().toString());
   editor.commit();
```

Now I want to check if secretKey already exists or not in the sharedprefrences.

Comment: Okay thanx a lot.I am trying to implement the method.If it doesnt work I will tell you. :)

Comment: And how to retrieve result for this key value pair??

Answer (score 3):

It is simple. There is a method:

```
public abstract boolean contains (String key)
```

You can read it here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in next way

```
sharedPref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedf",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String secretKey = sharedPref.getString("secretKey", null);
if (null == secretKey) {
    // not exists
} else {
    // exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     if (mPrefs.contains(SETTING_THEME)) {
                // read the value
                mThemeSettings = mPrefs.getString(SETTING_THEME, THEME_KEY_DEFAULT);
            } 
     // create a new "prefs entry" (first start, after installing the app)
     else mEditor.putString(SETTING_THEME, mThemeSettings).apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

[android: check if value exists in Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757573/android-check-if-value-exists-in-shared-preferences)

:-Check this

Try contains(String key) Accorting to the Javadocs,

Checks whether the preferences contains a preference. Returns true if the preference exists in the preferences, otherwise false.