# How to tell if my shared preferences already has a specific value

Tags: java, android, key, sharedpreferences

So I have some shared preferences:

```
 public SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.me1jmo.insult_generator", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And I am adding new key value pairs to it like so:

```
int number = prefs.getAll().size();
        int newkey = ++number;
        String newkeystring = "" + newkey;
        prefs.edit().putString(newkeystring,saved).commit();
```

However I don't want to add a string that has already been added. So I want to check that the string I am adding is not already a value in my shared preferences. What would be the best way to go about this?

(or could I just switch my values and keys around and check that I don't already have that key in my shared preferences)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: check if value is present in Shared Preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757573/android-check-if-value-is-present-in-shared-preferences)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17885456/1529129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `prefs.contains(newkeystring)` to check if an entry for that key exits already. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains(java.lang.String))

> Checks whether the preferences contains a preference.

**Edit**:

> My key will not already exist, they will always be different I want to
>   know if the value I'm entering is already in the preferences. –

Then the only solution is to loop and check if the value exits. The retrieve the `SharedPreferences` content you can use getAll (check my answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22089411/how-to-get-all-keys-of-sharedpreferences-programmatically-in-android))

```
public boolean exits(String value) {
    Map<String, ?> allEntries = prefA.getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
        Log.d("map values", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
        if ("yourvalue".equals(entry.getValue().toString()) {
            // the value exits; 
            return true;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

and call it like `exits("theValueToCheck);`

Comment: My key will not already exist, they will always be different I want to know if the value I'm entering is already in the preferences.