# Spinner with SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, spinner, android-sharedpreferences

Good evening.
I'm trying to save the choice the user makes in Spinner in SharedPreferences, when he clicks OK, but I'm not getting it, can anyone help me?
Then I want to redeem the choice made when it opens the application again and puts it in a textView.

Follow my code.

```
mShowDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEscolhaCidade);

    mShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_spinner, null);
            mBuilder.setTitle("Em qual Cidade Você está?");

            final Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) mView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cidades));
            adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter3);

            mBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (!mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Escolha uma Cidade")) {
                        cidade_Escolhida.setText(mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences2.edit();
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.cidade_escolhida_salvo), mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        editor.apply();

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });

            mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();

                }
            });
            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: First you should check if the shared preference exists or not,  if it does not exists do nothing and if it exists retrieve its value and set in text view and spinner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: check if value exists in Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757573/android-check-if-value-exists-in-shared-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

check this,

```
public class PreferenceManager {
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


public PreferenceManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("General", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.apply();
}

public void saveString(String key, String value) {
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getString(String key) {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "NA");
}
}
```

to save the string

```
PreferenceManager preferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(context);
preferenceManager.saveString("key","StringValue");
```

get the stored string like this

```
 PreferenceManager preferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(context);
 String savedString = preferenceManager.getString("key");
```